# Swift. Same menu overlay on multiple View Controllers

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, menu

Okay I have created this menu in my first view controller:

[image]

Now the thing is, I want the same menu to be on all of my other view controller as well, and there must be some easier way to do it, than recreating it by hand on every single view controller.

But I dont know how, can someone help me out?

Comment: The best way is to make it with code. Create new View via code and at all viewControllers, you can addSubview() this custom menu.

Comment: Copy paste all those?

Comment: The problem is when I just copy it, the constraints will be messed up